# AuthBot / BotAuth : how to set the authentification without magic number

Tags: .net, authentication, botframework

I'm trying to create a bot in which the user has to first authentificate. I'm well aware of drawbacks when not using magic number validation, however i want the user to authentificate directly when clicking on the link. 
The bot that im using is this [AuthBot](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot/tree/master/AuthBot).

This is the method that verify the magic number when put by the user :

```
public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {
            var msg = await argument;

            AuthResult authResult;
            string validated = "";
            int magicNumber = 0;
            if (context.UserData.TryGetValue(ContextConstants.AuthResultKey, out authResult))
            {
                try
                {
                    //IMPORTANT: DO NOT REMOVE THE MAGIC NUMBER CHECK THAT WE DO HERE. THIS IS AN ABSOLUTE SECURITY REQUIREMENT
                    //REMOVING THIS WILL REMOVE YOUR BOT AND YOUR USERS TO SECURITY VULNERABILITIES. 
                    //MAKE SURE YOU UNDERSTAND THE ATTACK VECTORS AND WHY THIS IS IN PLACE.
                    context.UserData.TryGetValue<string>(ContextConstants.MagicNumberValidated, out validated);
                    if (validated == "true")
                    {
                        context.Done($"Thanks {authResult.UserName}. You are now logged in. ");
                    }
                    else if (context.UserData.TryGetValue<int>(ContextConstants.MagicNumberKey, out magicNumber))
                    {
                        if (msg.Text == null)
                        {
                            await context.PostAsync($"Please paste back the number you received in your authentication screen.");

                            context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
                        }
                        else
                        {

                            if (msg.Text.Length >= 6 && magicNumber.ToString() == msg.Text.Substring(0, 6))
                            {
                                context.UserData.SetValue<string>(ContextConstants.MagicNumberValidated, "true");
                                context.Done($"Thanks {authResult.UserName}. You are now logged in. ");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                context.UserData.RemoveValue(ContextConstants.AuthResultKey);
                                context.UserData.SetValue<string>(ContextConstants.MagicNumberValidated, "false");
                                context.UserData.RemoveValue(ContextConstants.MagicNumberKey);
                                await context.PostAsync($"I'm sorry but I couldn't validate your number. Please try authenticating once again. ");

                                context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    context.UserData.RemoveValue(ContextConstants.AuthResultKey);
                    context.UserData.SetValue(ContextConstants.MagicNumberValidated, "false");
                    context.UserData.RemoveValue(ContextConstants.MagicNumberKey);
                    context.Done($"I'm sorry but something went wrong while authenticating.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await this.CheckForLogin(context, msg);
            }
        }
```

Someone show me how to not to use magic number in the process of authentificating ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bot Framework has recently enabled [Authentication using Sign-in Cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0). You no longer need to use BotAuth or AuthBot.  Included with this new feature is the ability to not use the magic number flow.  You do still have the option to use it if you would like though.

In the [GitHubBot sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/GitHubBot) you can find an example of using a 3rd party OAuth provider.

In the [BasicOAuth sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/Microsoft.Bot.Sample.BasicOAuth).  There is an example of using your own OAuth provider.

Then there is 2 AAD samples for [AADV1](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AadV1Bot) and [AADV2](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AadV2Bot)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Botauth](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth) and not [Authbot](https://github.com/Ellerbach/SharePointBot/tree/master/AuthBot) as the Authbot project has been discontinued and is not updated to the latest bot framework changes.
[image: Authbot discontinued]

Now not using `magic number` will cause a serious security vulnerability. As quoted in [docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/botauth/tree/master/CSharp#magic-numbers) :

> The UseMagicNumber property was added to the AuthenticationOptions class to allow the magic number to be turned off. However, the introduction of this property was likely a mistake as it is a serious security vulnerability and has since been marked obsolete. To explain the security vulnerability, you need to understand how the auth flow works. When it is determined the bot user does not have a valid token, BotAuth generates a URL for the user to initiate an authentication flow. This URL includes all the conversation parameters encrypted in the state parameter so the callback controller can continue the conversation after acquiring a token. **Without the magic number, a user could send someone else this URL and (if clicked) get access to their token**.

Now in case if you still want to turn it off, **again though it's not advisable**, what you have to do in [Authbot](https://github.com/Ellerbach/SharePointBot/tree/master/AuthBot) is set the `UseMagicNumber` property to false.

The code would be something like :

```
// Initialize AuthenticationOptions and forward to AuthDialog for token
AuthenticationOptions options = new AuthenticationOptions()
{
    Authority = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.Authority"],
    ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.ClientId"],
    ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.ClientSecret"],
    ResourceId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.ResourceId"],
    RedirectUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ActiveDirectory.RedirectUrl"],
    UseMagicNumber = false
};

await context.Forward(new AuthDialog(new ADALAuthProvider(), options), this.ResumeAfterAuth, message, CancellationToken.None);
```